# Using a dynamic named range to link to the last cell on a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I'm using the formula =OFFSET(A1,Counta(A:A)+1,0).

The intention is to create a button that will link to this dynamic named range (single cell) that will allow users to skip to the bottom of the table and add a new row to the table.

However, whenever I create this named range, it doesn't appear in the Name Box list of Names, and it doesn't appear in the list of named ranges I can link to when I create a link. I can, however, type the name into the name box directly, and it will take me to the correct cell.

I've done this before, so I can't work out where it's going wrong. Am I doing something stupid, or is Excel being funny?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but suggest first of all that you use fixed ranges like =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)+1,0) otherwise the cell depends on where you reference it from. Also note that this gives you a position two rows below the last cell with data. Apart from this, it works for me.

Comment: I missed the $ out for quickness of typing, but yes, it works, it goes to the correct cell, but it won't turn up in the list of names I can link to when I create a link. Does that bit work for you? 

I just realised, on inspecting the similar work I did before, I ended up using a hyperlink formula, and constructing the cell reference with the COUNTA(A:A) that way. But that's a very unsatisfactory solution, I'd rather make a button in this case.

Comment: I see what you mean - if I define a name 'test' as a cell address like $A$1, then create a hyperlink to a place in this document, it does show in the list of available names, but with your formula it doesn't. Maybe it's because it has to be evaluated. Will play around with it a bit more.

Comment: I think anything that looks like a formula (offset, index, indirect...) doesn't work unfortunately